# Ожидание завершения post запроса, перед выполнением следующего

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники сообщества.
У меня возникла проблема следующего характера: Я пишу скрипт, который последовательно отправляет два post запроса на сервер и сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что иногда первый запрос не успевает выполниться перед тем, как это сделал второй запрос и я получил от второго запроса ошибочные данные...
То есть вопрос заключается в том, как мне заставить программу дождаться выполнения этого первого post запроса?

```
$.post("/").done(function(data)
{
    $(document).html(data);
});

$.post("/").done(function(data)
{
    $(document).html(data);
});
```

Comment: Javascript всегда выполняет запросы параллельно. Поэтому единственный способ выполнять их последовательно - отправлять следующий запрос в обработчике ответа предыдущего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post("/").done(function(data)
{
    $(document).html(data);
    $.post("/").done(function(data)
    {
        $(document).html(data);
    });
});
```